# Py2Exe Error: Win32com.client causes errors when trying to run created executable

Tags: python, py2exe, importerror, win32com

My script that I'm trying to create into an executable contains the following imports:

```
import csv, time, BeautifulSoup, sys, mechanize, os, traceback, win32com.client as win32
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "tool.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

The .exe of my program is created successfully, however when I try to run it I receive the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tool.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "win32com\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading win32api.pyd
```

Surprisingly, it compiles into an .exe fine if I use `bundle_files: = 3` however I need this program to be in one executable, not multiple files. I've read [this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/UsingEnsureDispatch) from the py2exe website but I'm not sure if that's what I need to do/use. If that is the answer I'm looking for, I don't know how to use that or what to do with it. Please explain.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by upgrading to Python 2.7. I originally had Python 2.6 installed but the update solved this issue.